# can we do client side search filter in jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

Am loading data into a jqGrid from a XML String, on which i want to apply a search filter- client side. how do i do it?

i have included the following code after the jqGrid definition and the tool bar is getting displayed with all the fields for search with various conditions. But when i enter the search data and enter search- its not displaying any records. what should i do? please help me!

```
jQuery("#list").navGrid("#myPager",{search:true, edit:false, del:false, add:false});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should correctly define [sorttype](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options) property in every column. If the standard types don't get you the results which you need you can define `sorttype` as function.

To be able to help you more one need see the jqGrid definition which you use and the test XML data which you use.